# How to place a dash or underline in between letters but lower than other letters using css

Tags: css, text

I'd like to have the following written in css where the underline is positioned lower down than the other letters.

Almost like a vertical indentation

**co_defy**

It would be great to have the dash at the same level as the bottom of the y.

Is this possible?

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/50r279Ln/ ?

Comment: please post this as an answer - perfect, simple and elegant solution!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adjust `vertical-align` of the underscore

```css
body {
  font-size:60px;
  font-family:arial;
}
span {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
co<span>_</span>defy
```

You can also use custom values to adjust like you want:

```css
body {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: arial;
}

span {
  vertical-align: -0.1em;
}
```

```html
co<span>_</span>defy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text-underline-position` property in CSS. Like so:

```
.example {

    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
    -ms-text-underline-position: below;
}
```

As you can see, IE and Edge have a different syntax for the property. Hope this works!

Another way to do it is as such:

```css
body {
  font-size: 50px;
}

span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
co<span>_</span>defy
```